# sed: use backreferences to index array

Tags: sed

**test_file.txt** 
1X2X3X 
1X3X2X 
3X1X2X

**sed_script.sh**

```
    export list=("zero" "one" "two" "three")
    sed 's/\(.*\)X\(.*\)X\(.*\)X/a=\1 b='"${list[\2]}"' c=\3/'  test_file.txt
```

**output**

```
 a=1 b=two c=3 
 a=1 b=two c=2 
 a=3 b=two c=2
```

index for 'list' is always set as '2' for all the cases. I am trying to use the backreference value.

**expected output**

```
a=1 b=two c=3 
a=1 b=three c=2
a=3 b=one c=2
```

Can anyone suggest how to use backreference value '\2' to index the array 'list' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The back-references do not work the way you would like.  For what you ask `awk` is the more natural tool:

```
$ awk -FX 'BEGIN{split("zero one two three", a, / /)} {printf "a=%s b=%s c=%s\n",$1,a[$2+1],$3}' test_file.txt 
a=1 b=two c=3
a=1 b=three c=2
a=3 b=one c=2
```

#### How it works

- `-FX`

  This makes awk treat the letter `X` as the field separator.
- `BEGIN{split("zero one two three", a, / /)}`

  This defines the array `a`, analogous to your shell variable `list`.
- `printf "a=%s b=%s c=%s\n",$1,a[$2+1],$3`

  This prints out the line the format in your selected format.

  (Since awk arrays have an index-origin of 1, we have to add one to the index to get it to match the right entry.)